# Multiple systems in a 1u rackmount case?

Tags: rackmount

Is there a provider or simple custom build method to fit one or more seperated physical systems (anything able to run server CPUs, with or without HDD) in a 1u rackmount chassis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supermicro has the Twin series: 1U with 2 boards and 4 boards in 2U (with redundant PSU)

Answer (score 3):

ASUS makes a 1U server that should work for you, the [RS702D-E6/PS8](http://usa.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=GIBHyMbU5MuyzDo6&templete=3)

> Supporting Intel® Xeon® 5500 series processor, RS702D, the dual 2-Processor systems provide extreme performance for customers with 4-way, 16-core computing capability in 1U. The design of 1~8 hot swap 2.5” SATA/SAS HDDs support is space-saving with its normal form factor.

Answer (score 0):

There are providers that will do you four servers per 2 units, by combining two servers into 1RU. Both Dell and HP have offerings in this regard, but I can't seem to find the links to either of them at the moment.

So, if you're looking to squeeze two servers into 1RU, then no, but if you want 4 servers in 2RU, then yes.